# Get value from other row in same group in r

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
date_nba <- tibble::tribble(
   ~idGame, ~slugTeam, ~slugOpponent, ~drebTeam, ~orebTeam,
  20900001,     "NOP",         "TOR",        37,        16,
  20900001,     "TOR",         "NOP",        41,        16,
  20900002,     "LAL",         "LAC",        32,         9,
  20900002,     "LAC",         "LAL",        34,        11
  )
```

I want to create a column called **drebOpp**, which is the drebTeam from the other slugTeam in the same idGame. So the desired result would be:

```
tibble::tribble(
   ~idGame, ~slugTeam, ~slugOpponent, ~drebTeam, ~orebTeam, ~drebOpp,
  20900001,     "NOP",         "TOR",        37,        16,       41,
  20900001,     "TOR",         "NOP",        41,        16,       37,
  20900002,     "LAL",         "LAC",        32,         9,       34,
  20900002,     "LAC",         "LAL",        34,        11,       32
  )
```

I know there's probably an easy solution using group_by and mutate, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a group by `match`

```
library(dplyr)
date_nba %>% 
  group_by(idGame) %>% 
  mutate(drebOpp = drebTeam[match(slugTeam, slugOpponent)])
```